# Insert 2D Array into MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql

So i have a multidimensional array as follows:

```
int[][] multiarray = {
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },

};
```

I have a MySQL database with 5 columns:

```
|number1|number2|number3|number4|number5|
```

My question is, how would i insert this array into the mysql database?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a *table* with 5 columns?

Comment: @Strawberry because i have 5 columns in the 2d array. I would have assumed that therefore 5 was needed in the database? I am completely new to this kind of thing, so apologies if it does not make sense

Comment: You will create 5 `INSERT` statements (1 for each row) or a single batch statement for the same.

Comment: You are familiar with [`JDBC`](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/), right?

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks for the reply, however can you let me know in a bit more detail on the code aspect of this?

Comment: Do you know how to [iterate through arrays](http://codingbat.com/doc/java-array-loops.html)?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, but the complicated bit is on how to make sure a specific e.g element on (0,0) (i.e. ele 1 on x axis and ele 1 on Y axis) will go to the relevant place on the database.

Comment: @user1423798 That is a false assumption. And I'm afraid the other answers here have rather led you astray. A database table is not a spreadsheet. See normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry i think its a good starting point. It does what i want it to, although it may not be the best way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code should look somewhat like this, won't give you the exact answer as it looks like a homework problem:

```
db.setAutoCommit(false);
stm = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (NUMBER1,NUMBER2 ,NUMBER3, NUMBER4, NUMBER5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){ // rows 
        stm.setString(1, multiarray[i][0]);  
        stm.setString(2, multiarray[i][1]); 
        stm.setString(3, multiarray[i][2]); 
        stm.setString(4, multiarray[i][3]); 
        stm.setString(5, multiarray[i][4]);      
        stm.addBatch();
}
stm.executeBatch();
db.commit();
```

Comment: Actually, this is not a homework problem. I actually wont study java until next year. Im experimenting with stuff till then. However, i have no idea on how to code this which is why i posted here for help.

Comment: @user1423798 Changed my answer. This is what should work for you.

Comment: i will test this, and let you know if this works. Thanks for your time Sir. Very much appreciated!

Comment: This worked! Thank you Sir.

Comment: Now if i was to get it to retrieve the multiarray into a variable such as int[][] array; , how would i achieve this?

Comment: I currently have the following, which works but only retrieves the values in the first row, i.e. 0,1,0,1,0 pastie.org/private/pxrhqs0q7bekvsjkyf7oa

Comment: @user1423798 while retrieving do the same. Run a for loop and for each row assign array[i][1] = value from the columns

Comment: this code does not work:
array[i][j] = result.getInt("NUMBER1");

Comment: Check for the syntax. The syntax is wrong.

Comment: Check the link. Have a variable i , which should increase on every iteration. Then do arr[i][1] = rs.getInt("Number1"). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html. I can send you a code once I reach home.

Comment: Yes that is what i did. See here (http://pastie.org/private/exit6wgqu8wtsrjr378j2g). I get a nullpointer exception error.

Comment: okay, so i managed to get it working. But now, if i do a system.print output, i get all the integers one by one without any comma's like the format specified on my original post of the multidimensional array. How can i get it to this format?